# mapquest batch geocoding truncate response

Tags: geocoding, batch, mapquest

when I use the batch geocoding service I get sometimes a right answer an sometimes an error using the same arguments. I inspect the headers using curl...

when the answer is right the headers are:

```
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.mapquestapi.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D76103E6D445BBCBF91B16094ABDCE2A; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 18:26:28 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,POST
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 18:26:27 GMT
<
{.... correct message ...}
```

but when the answer is wrong the headers are the following, note that content-length is setted and the message is truncate resulting into an invalid json.

```
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0 
> Host: www.mapquestapi.com
> Accept: */* 
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A7DC145B948D28B4D23E914379DCD012; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 22:44:06 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,POST
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 253
< Date: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 22:44:05 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.mapquestapi.com left intact
{"info":{"statuscode":0,"copyright":{"text":"\u00A9 2014 MapQuest,     Inc.","imageUrl":"https://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif","imageAltText":"\u00A9 2014 MapQuest, Inc."},"messages":[]},"options":{"maxResults":1,"thumbMaps":false,"ignoreLatLngInput":false}
```

This is the query:

```
https://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/batch?key=Fmjtd%7Cluur2q6b2h%2Can%3Do5-9a2xhu&json={"locations": [{"street": ", Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Camino Ochagavia 12301, San Bernardo, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Los Yacimientos 1301, Maipu, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Las Nieves 331, Vitacura, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Camino Lo Sierra 04330, San Bernardo, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Pedro de Valdivia 3128, \u00d1u\u00f1oa, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Merced 838, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Canal Concepcion Sur 2310, Maipu, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Luis Pasteur 6156, Vitacura, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "San Francisco 9128, San Ramon, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida 4\u00b0 CENTENARIO 196, Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Condell 1213, Providencia, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "San Sebastian 2812 , Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Isabel la Catolica 4448, Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Del Inca 4446, Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida 10 de Julio Huamachuco 542, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Enrique Mac-Iver 180, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Santa Corina 0473, La Cisterna, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Departamental 7480, Pe\u00f1alolen, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Libertad 720, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida La Florida 10139, La Florida, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Concha y Toro 2990, Puente Alto, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Manuel Antonio Tocornal 2359, San Joaquin, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Antillanca Sur 611, Pudahuel, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Andres Bello 2777, Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Santo Domingo 445, Puente Alto, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Apoquindo 6415, Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Puerto Santiago 153, Pudahuel, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Mariano Sanchez Fontecila 9150, La Florida, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida 5 de Abril 5817, Estacion Central, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Chacabuco 79, Maipu, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Santa Josefina 12502, San Bernardo, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Siglo XV 10623, La Pintana, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Carmen Mena 545, San Miguel, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Los Pinos 761, Cerrillos, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Pasaje 5 Norte 0595, La Granja, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Divino Maestro 7282, Cerrillos, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Lo Gallo 1893, Vitacura, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "General Del Canto 230, Providencia, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "\u00d1uble 350, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Providencia 2315, Providencia, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Constantino 590, Quinta Normal, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida San Francisco 9075, Cerro Navia, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Providencia 395, Providencia, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Joaquin Diaz Garces 8833, La Cisterna, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "San Pedro 312, La Florida, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "San Antonio 418, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Pasaje Ignacio Zuazagoitia 3189, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Ossa 1771, San Ramon, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Libertador Bernardo OHiggins 3287, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Augusto Biaut 0726, La Cisterna, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Zurich Norte 087, La Cisterna, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Rosas 1869, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Doctor Amador Neghme Ro 03639, La Pintana, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Manuel Antonio Matta 1222, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "3, Quinta Normal, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Pasaje Doctor Sotero del Rio 508, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Toesca 2698, Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Apoquindo 6415, Las Condes, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Aeropuerto 9970, Cerrillos, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Padre Hurtado 13376, El Bosque, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Cam del Marques 2281, Lo Barnechea, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}, {"street": "Avenida Alcalde Carlos Valdovinos 2898, Pedro Aguirre Cerda, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana, Chile"}], "options": {"thumbMaps": "false", "maxResults": "1"}}
```

I don't think is a problem with my connection because the headers answered would be the same.

is there something missing in my request?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Could you please edit this question to make it clearer what you're asking? It appears that there's a problem with the MapQuest API, or your connection to it, if the query works intermittently. How can we help?